# Does anyone know of a good set of installation instructions for Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to get started with Node.js on a Windows machine.  Yes, I found the installer on their site.  That worked just fine and I can run it.  However, after that there's no instructions or requirements.  Some issues I ran into:

- I learned that most of these cool modules need to be built locally.
- I was told I needed Git installed
- I found I needed Python to build modules
- I discovered I needed Visual Studio to compile
- Once things are built they should be executable.  However, they are not natively found in the path.  I discovered them under `%APPDATA%\npm`, but there's no mention of adding that to the PATH.

What else am I going to discover?  Is there a guide to this anywhere?

Comment: Could you elaborate on which modules are giving you issues?  In my experience a simple `npm install {nameOfModule}` works 99%.

Comment: I've been specifically trying to get started with Ember.  So I went through the above process in order to make `npm install -g ember` to work.  But even so, I'm still not sure that the last step is the correct way of gaining access to the globally installed modules.

Comment: Never used Ember, and I agree with you that the docs are confusing.  True of many node modules.  Suggest that you clarify your question.  You are having problems installing Ember fo Node, not with Node itself.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Altough I might suggest you to develope node on a unix based os (Ubuntu 12.04+WebStorm is my favorite combination for many reasons I can mention) I found my self in your situation at work when Windows 7 is a must.

[I found this video really helpful](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tlntE8fe6u4)

Once youe have node installed on your machine (window or any other) I (and most community) would recommend you to use [WebStorm as IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/nodejs.html) it contains every inch of support to make your development process easy and clean, mange your global and local modules and build/debug your code easily.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've actually installed Node.js fine, but are having problems with the packages built by people in the community, some of which use Python or a native C compiler.  Git shouldn't be necessary unless you're perhaps cloning projects from a remote repository?  Or maybe the packages have dependencies on projects hosted in GitHub?

Keep in mind that Node is separate from all the modules and packages available in the community, accessed through [the npm registry](https://www.npmjs.org/).  Node provides you the ability to execute JavaScript locally, [additional APIs](http://nodejs.org/api/), and an ecosystem to build additional packages which can do, as you've said, really cool things.  But each of these packages can have unique installation requirements.

Most packages have dependencies of their own, and are often installed using the `npm install` command.  This (usually) downloads other packages from https://www.npmjs.org/, and in some cases requires compiling additional files.  This might have been the issue you hit.

The other thing to keep in mind is that a lot of people might assume things are installed and available since they have it installed for them, or are running a different operating system than you.  I've often found that folks will hard code `/` somewhere in their scripts, which cause problems on Windows based systems.  This can lead to problems with the executables that are created as part of the node packages created by the community.

To better understand what Node has and what's available, I'd recommend the [nodeschool.io projects](http://nodeschool.io/).  These cover some of the main areas provided by the base Node platform, and get you used to playing around with things from GitHub and npm.  Maybe if you run into specific issues there folks can help more directly.